# How to extract the date component from multiple datetime columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Data Set that looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'ProcessStartDate': ['08/11/2019 22:59', '07/11/2019 16:18', '04/12/2019 15:00', '24/06/2019 14:20', '24/04/2019 19:16'],
        'ValidationEndTime': ['27/11/2019 11:47', np.nan, np.nan, '28/06/2019 16:23', np.nan],
        'ValidationStartTime': ['08/11/2019 22:59', '06/01/2020 13:52', '27/11/2019 11:47', '24/06/2019 16:44', '10/07/2019 17:41'],
        'AiSStartTime': ['25/03/2020 11:18', '25/03/2020 11:18', '25/03/2020 08:14', '14/08/2019 15:43', '28/06/2019 16:23'],
        'AiSEndTime': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '26/08/2019 14:17', '14/08/2019 15:43']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   ProcessStartDate ValidationEndTime ValidationStartTime      AiSStartTime        AiSEndTime
0  08/11/2019 22:59  27/11/2019 11:47    08/11/2019 22:59  25/03/2020 11:18               NaN
1  07/11/2019 16:18               NaN    06/01/2020 13:52  25/03/2020 11:18               NaN
2  04/12/2019 15:00               NaN    27/11/2019 11:47  25/03/2020 08:14               NaN
3  24/06/2019 14:20  28/06/2019 16:23    24/06/2019 16:44  14/08/2019 15:43  26/08/2019 14:17
4  24/04/2019 19:16               NaN    10/07/2019 17:41  28/06/2019 16:23  14/08/2019 15:43
```

what i need is to extract the date part of every column and put it into a new column named as the columns where the date is concatenated with 'new'. the columns are objects so i can transform them all to datetime format with this code:

```py
cols = ['ProcessStartDate','ValidationEndTime','ValidationStartTime','AiSStartTime','AiSEndTime']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

I would have thought that I could have extracted the dates from all the columns using the same code as above but adding the `dt.date` but this raises an exception.

I also have searched SO for an answer but I have only been able to find answers that deal with doing this  for one column and not multiple.

Answer (score 0):

- As stated in the OP, all of the columns can be converted to a datetime format:

  - `df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)`

```py
# extract the date component from the columns
df_new = df.apply(lambda col: col.dt.date)

# add _new to the column names
df_new.columns = [f'{v}_new' for v in df_new.columns]

# display(df_new)
  ProcessStartDate_new ValidationEndTime_new ValidationStartTime_new AiSStartTime_new AiSEndTime_new
0           2019-08-11            2019-11-27              2019-08-11       2020-03-25            NaT
1           2019-07-11                   NaT              2020-06-01       2020-03-25            NaT
2           2019-04-12                   NaT              2019-11-27       2020-03-25            NaT
3           2019-06-24            2019-06-28              2019-06-24       2019-08-14     2019-08-26
4           2019-04-24                   NaT              2019-10-07       2019-06-28     2019-08-14
```

- Alternatively, the transformation can be done in a single `.apply`

```py
df_new = df.apply(lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col).dt.date)
```